# run controller function based on previous state name

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have an app with states including intro, account, etc..
I want to run openModal function in account controller only if previous state was intro.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
in app.js:

```
// recording previous state name
```

.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
    $state.previous = fromState;
  });
})

in controller:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
  if($state.previous.name=='intro')
    $scope.showCardModal();
})
```

Listener in controller needed because in cached view ionic run controller only first time